# How can I limit returned number of record for a specific value of column in inner query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I'm querying a postgres database for fetching 5 messages of each conversation user is involved in 
here is the query

```
select conversation.id, message from conversation inner join
(select conversation.id as conversationId, conversation_reply.message 
  from conversation_reply
  inner join  conversation on conversation.id = conversation_reply.c_id
  where conversation.user_one=22 or conversation.user_two=22 order by 
conversation_reply.time DESC limit 5) as messages on 
messages.conversationid = conversation.id
```

this produces following result

```
80  jay%3A%20hello
80  jay%3A%20hey
80  jay%3A%20do%20this%20too
80  jay%3A%20throw%20please
80  jay%3A%20should%20be%20thrown
```

these are all the messages of conversation user having id 22 has been involved in, now i want to limit only 5 messages of each conversation such that

```
80 80msg1
80 80msg2
80 80msg3
80 80msg4
80 80msg5
73 73msg1
73 73msg2
73 73msg3
73 73msg4
73 73msg5
72 72msg1
72 72msg2
72 72msg3
```

this way i only have upto 5 messages of each conversation of user 22, how can i do that? how limit works on inner queries?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from your table?

Comment: yes sure, should i be posting a screenshot?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Ideally a table is described with it's `CREATE` statement and `INSERT` statements with some sample data.

Comment: You can post format data instead of screenshot thankts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a lateral join is the best way to solve this:

```
SELECT c.id as conversationId,
       cr.message 
FROM conversation AS c
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      (SELECT message
       FROM conversation_reply
       WHERE c.id = conversation_reply.c_id
       ORDER BY conversation_reply.time DESC
       LIMIT 5) AS cr
WHERE c.user_one = 22
   OR c.user_two = 22;
```

With `LATERAL` you can use attributes from `conversation` on the right side of the join.

Comment: but when using any other  join except crossjoin with it, this reports expected inner, full, right, left,cross but got where.

Comment: Then maybe you made a syntax error. I used cross join here because you want all 5 records joined with every matching row.

Answer (score 2):

I can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` with *window function* to make rowNumber instead of `limit`.

```
select conversation.id, message 
from conversation inner join
(
    select 
        conversation.id as conversationId, 
        conversation_reply.message,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY messages.conversationid order by conversation_reply.time DESC) rn
      from conversation_reply
      inner join  conversation on conversation.id = conversation_reply.c_id
      where conversation.user_one= 22 or conversation.user_two=22 
) as messages on 
messages.conversationid = conversation.id
WHERE rn <= 5
```

Comment: this does work with slight change though as the messages table is not recognized before it's  definition in inner query, Lateral Join as @Laurenz Albe mentioned, handles this well, thank you i'll vote this up :)